# Deriving unbiasedness of estimators (involving method of moments idea) of normal distribution with heterogeneous variance

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, inference, unbiased-estimator, method-of-moments

I am currently reading [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-statistics/volume-2/issue-1/In-season-prediction-of-batting-averages--A-field-test/10.1214/07-AOAS138.full) and in pp.127, 128, there are unbiased estimators that I cannot derive its unbiasedness.

The setting is simple. Let $$X_i\sim N(\mu,\tau^2+\sigma_i^2),\quad i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$$ where $\mu$ and $\tau$ are parameters to be estimated and $\sigma_i$ are known constants that may differ between each other.

Then in p.127 equation (4.6), the paper presents estimators of $\mu$ and $\tau$ that "involves Method of Moments idea" as the following.

\begin{align}
\tilde\mu&=\frac{\sum X_i/(\tilde\tau^2+\sigma_i^2)}{\sum1/(\tilde\tau^2+\sigma_i^2)}\tag{1}\\
\tilde\tau^2&=\frac{\sum(X_i-\tilde\mu)^2-((n-1)/n)\sum\sigma_i^2}{n-1}\tag{2}
\end{align}

At p.128, the paper asserts that $E(\tilde\mu)=\mu$ and $E(\tilde\tau^2)=\tau^2$ without any hints or proofs.

My plan was to rearrange the above equations into $\tilde\mu=\dots$ and $\tilde\tau=\dots$ form by plugging in $\tilde\tau^2$ in (1) and $\tilde\mu$ in (2). But if you try plugging in $\tilde\tau^2$ in (1), the equation seems unsolvable. Is my strategy not suitable for checking unbiasedness? Then what is an appropriate method?

Comment: If $\tau$ was known, I can understand $\frac{\sum X_i/(\tau^2+\sigma_i^2)}{\sum1/(\tau^2+\sigma_i^2)}$ is the best linear unbiased estimator of $\mu$. Not sure how they found $\tilde\tau^2$ so that when $\tau^2$ is replaced by $\tilde\tau^2$, the resulting estimator remains unbiased for $\mu$.